# Files in Document Library are re-selected and erroneously marked as requiring attention after bulk upload and edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload

**Desired Behaviour**

1. Upload multiple files to Document Library (eg 150 files)
2. Wait till they have finished uploading (all 150 files will be selected by default)
3. Click `Properties` and edit the properties of all 150 files
4. Click `Save`
5. Wait till they have finished saving
6. Files should be unselected and the Properties pane should no longer be visible

**Actual Behaviour**

Everything occurs as desired except for step 6.

What actually happens at that point is shown in the screenshot below, ie:

- A seemingly arbitrary number of files are selected
- The Properties panel is still visible and displays the error message:

```
This file is missing required information
```

[image]

**Workaround**

If I click on the `X` next to `30 selected` and reload the page, all changes have been saved and there is no error message.

**Why This Is A Problem**

The above workaround is not a satisfactory solution as other, less tech savvy, users will be confused that after bulk uploading, editing and saving changes to 150 files, they are still seeing  an error message that files are missing required information.  It is also confusing that an arbitrary number of files are still selected (rather than being unselected) and this could lead to more unintentional changes being made to files as users make multiple attempts to resolve the `required information` error message.

It seems the default functionality is missing an automatic 'refresh' action which:

- unselects files
- closes the Properties pane
- removes the 'red dot' icon that indicates files 'require attention'

**Environment**

Browser: Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)
SharePoint Online
Microsoft Team SharePoint Site Document Library

Comment: Your best course of action is to open a support case with Microsoft and possibly submit a Design Change Request (which requires a support case).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am a project administrator in a large organisation and don't have access to Microsoft support channels.  I suppose I could submit a ticket to IT advising them of the behaviour and ask them to create a Microsoft support ticket.  In my experience with large organisations, however, they are often reluctant to do that.

Comment: The cases are free, but there's no solution we can offer you here since it is product behavior you're looking at.

Comment: Have submitted ticket to IT requesting creation of Microsoft support ticket.